# Implementing Verkle Trees in Solidity, Generating Proofs, and Using Zokrates

Tags: solidity, remix, blockchain, zokrates

I'm working on implementing Verkle Trees and looking for guidance on how to implement Verkle Trees in Solidity. I have a working python code with implementation of verkle trees, proof generation and verification. But, I need to use it in Remix IDE. Could someone tell me what libraries are supported in solidity for polynomial commitments and elliptic curve operations?

I'm also curious about the feasibility of using Zokrates for generating and verifying proofs for Verkle Trees. If Zokrates is suitable, can someone provide a step-by-step guide or example code on how to implement Verkle Tree proofs using Zokrates?